# SSL VirtualHost showing test page

Tags: apache, configuration, virtualhost

I am using Apache httpd and have the following VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.test.site
    ServerAlias test.site
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/test.site/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test.site/log/requests.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.site
    ServerAlias test.site
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/html
</VirtualHost>
```

When entering http://test.site in my browser, I see what I want to see.
However, https://test.site returns the Apache test page, even though I specified literally the same DocumentRoot.

What could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

I tried changing the VirtualHost configuration.
I created new certificates, there are no errors with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the problem.
In the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ folder, there is an ssl.conf, which contains:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

Deleting this, or changing `default` to `123.123.123.123`, solves the problem, although it is arguably not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete file 000-default.conf or 000-default-ssl.conf from dir sites-enabled, if exist this one.

Then change

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.site
    ServerAlias test.site
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/html
</VirtualHost>
```

To

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.site
    ServerAlias test.site
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.site/html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.site [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =test.site
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Good practice to make dummy virtualhost to first place on virtualhost config, like below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [G]
</VirtualHost>
```

Maybe it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
There is already no default configuration present, and the proposed changes have unfortunately not yet solved the problem.